# write a text with multiple fonts in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I am currently using [Intervention](https://github.com/Intervention/image) class to write a text on images.

writing is easily possible using `text()` method:

```
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);
```

[Documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/text)

but my problem is that I want each character of a word with a different font. for example, imagine the word `test`, each character must use a different font. this is not easily possible since I can't find the position to start the next character, for instance in the word `test`, when I write `t` then when I want to call the `text()` method to write `e`, I don't know where should I set the position so the character `e` goes right after `t`.

**How** can I get the `position` of the last character so I can start writing the next character where the last one ends? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I use some method on my webpage but I can't remember what it is. And not sure it will work for you. But I'm going to bed now, can look at it tomorrow if you still have not solved it. Just @ me so I don't forget this thread.

Comment: @Andreas @ you :)

Comment: Haha! Still in bed. But I will look at it when i fall out of bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I use to get the width of a string.
I use imagettftext(), so it may not suit you. But this code works.
So if you have to choose between nothing and a code that works...

```
$type_space = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text); // 0 = angle
$text_width = abs($type_space[4] - $type_space[6]);
```

imagettfbbox returns an array of values.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

> Imagettfbbox() returns an array with 8 elements representing four points making the bounding box of the text:
>   0   lower left corner, X position
>   1   lower left corner, Y position
>   2   lower right corner, X position
>   3   lower right corner, Y position
>   4   upper right corner, X position
>   5   upper right corner, Y position
>   6   upper left corner, X position
>   7   upper left corner, Y position

The code takes upper right x - upper left x which should mean width.